# linegoal and book

Tags: linegoal

lingoal not work correctly with book class

For example, an incorrect definition of length on first page:

First (you need 2 times recompile):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\newcommand{\linegoaltest}{\rule{\linegoal}{1pt}}

\begin{document}
0 \linegoaltest

00 \linegoaltest
\end{document}
```

And with second page (you need 3 times recompile):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\newcommand{\linegoaltest}{\rule{\linegoal}{1pt}}

\begin{document}
0 \linegoaltest

00 \linegoaltest
\newpage
0 \linegoaltest

00 \linegoaltest
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add what the problem is? "lingoal not work correctly" is not a clear description for your problrm, I think ...

Comment: The problem is clearer if you add `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to the examples.

Comment: A quick look suggests that `\linegoal` on the odd pages is relying on an 'end of line' mark (via `zref` presumably) from the even pages, so it wrongly calculates how long the line should be. If you add the `verbose` option, you get to see the lengths it thinks it needs: `458.9544pt` and `453.4794pt` on page 1, and `422.09628pt` and `416.62128pt` on page 2.

Comment: For your particular example, why not `\hrulefill` instead of `\linegoaltest`?